# Backbone.Marionette - CollectionView with different ItemView classes

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I'm looking to re-build a vanilla `Backbone` app into a `Backbone.Marionette` based one. However, one of the existing views is giving me headache - a collection of different sub-views.

For exampe, the server returns a list that contains 100 entries, 50 items of type A, 49 items of type B and one C. Those then get grouped by type at client-side, and rendered as one `GroupView` that has the A entries, one `GroupView` for B entries, and one `EntryView` for C. `GroupView`s then can be expanded to show the individual `EntryView`s.

I can build a collection that contains three models - two `Group` models (with their respective `Entry` models inside), and one plain `Entry` model. But how do I tell the collection view to use `GroupView` to render `Group` models, and `EntryView` for `Entry` models?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override `CollectionView.getChildView` to decide which child view type to use for each model in the parent collection.

Assuming your `Model` types have a method called `isGroup` that returns a truthy value if the model is a `Group` or falsy otherwise:

```
var HeterogenousCollectionView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({

  getChildView: function(model) { 
    if(model.isGroup()) {
      return GroupView;
    } else {
      return EntryView;
    }
  }

})
```

See the [Marionette docs](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md#collectionviews-getchildview) for more detail. I also recommend browsing the [annotated source code](http://marionettejs.com/annotated-src/backbone.marionette) - it's concise enough to get a good feel for how Marionette view types work.

Comment: I also recommend a more descriptive view name than `HeterogenousCollectionView` ;-)

Comment: Thank you, precisely what I needed.

Comment: This is 100% correct, but just a heads up, in Marionette v1 this function is called `getItemView`.